# Dart: How to delete a specific value of a map with multiple values per key

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to delete all a's of this map. The b's should stay where they are. I'm new to programming, so I didn't find out how to do it. I need help.

When i print the Map named events (<DateTime, List>) i get this:

```
{
  2021-05-02 12:00:00.000Z: [a], 
  2021-05-03 12:00:00.000Z: [a, b], 
  2021-05-04 12:00:00.000Z: [a, b], 
  2021-05-05 12:00:00.000Z: [a], 
  2021-05-06 12:00:00.000Z: [a, b, b], 
  2021-05-07 12:00:00.000Z: [a]
}
```

Now I want to delete all of the a's, with some lines of code of course, so when i print the map it looks like this:

```
{
  2021-05-02 12:00:00.000Z: [], 
  2021-05-03 12:00:00.000Z: [b], 
  2021-05-04 12:00:00.000Z: [b], 
  2021-05-05 12:00:00.000Z: [], 
  2021-05-06 12:00:00.000Z: [b, b], 
  2021-05-07 12:00:00.000Z: []
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Your result seems to keep all the a:s. Do you want to keep them or remove them?

Comment: oh my bad, I meant to delete all the a's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the output you wrote, not deleting the a's:

```
final newMap = events.map((key, value) {
  value.removeWhere((element) => element != 'a');
  return MapEntry(key, value);
});
```

`events` is the map you start with...

This will produce the following output:

```
{
  2021-05-02 12:00:00.000Z: [a], 
  2021-05-03 12:00:00.000Z: [a], 
  2021-05-04 12:00:00.000Z: [a], 
  2021-05-05 12:00:00.000Z: [a], 
  2021-05-06 12:00:00.000Z: [a], 
  2021-05-07 12:00:00.000Z: [a]
}
```

If you want to delete all the a's, obviously replace the `!= 'a'` with `== 'a'` which will give you this output:

```
{
 2021-05-02 12:00:00.000Z: [], 
 2021-05-03 12:00:00.000Z: [b], 
 2021-05-04 12:00:00.000Z: [b], 
 2021-05-05 12:00:00.000Z: [], 
 2021-05-06 12:00:00.000Z: [b, b], 
 2021-05-07 12:00:00.000Z: []
}
```

Comment: Thank you, thats what I coudn't find on the internet for 2 hours. Perfect Solution for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Robert's answer will do what you want, but it will produce a new map every time it is run (which is preferable in some situations). For future readers who would rather operate on the `events` map directly in-place, here is an alternative to accomplish that:

```dart
events.values.forEach((list) => list.removeWhere((e) => e == 'a'));
```